# Handling grouping of case sensitive data in RDLC

Tags: sql, reporting, rdlc

I have an RDLC report, I have a column chart whose X axis is shows PerformedBy person names,
 Y axis shows the count of exams grouped by each PerformedBy person.
 The data in the dataset contains case sensitive data.
 For example, there are two PerformedBy names like 'john' and 'JOHN'. 
john has Number of exams as 1 where as JOHN has 2. Currently in the chart it displays only JOHN.
 The data for both 'john' and 'JOHN' are combined and shown under 'JOHN' as 3.
 I want to display  john with Number of exams as 1 and  JOHN with Number of exams as 2.
 How to handle this at RDLC level?

I have seen in some of the dicussions that I can select Data Options and then choose casesensitivity property.
 But I am not seeing this option in Dataset Properties dialog.It shows only the option General.
 I am using Visual studio 2010 , .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 Express.

Another option I was thinking to add a Unique identifier field for the Performed By person in the dataset. In the chart
 how do I group by Identifier but then display Performed by Name in X axis?

Note that I saw both records are coming in my output collection from sql query.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the string to ASCII code, and then put the number together

For instance 'john' => '106111104110' and John=> '74111104110'. And then group on that value

This link will explain how to convert a string to an ASCII values.

http://p2p.wrox.com/beginning-vb-6/56056-converting-set-string-its-ascii-value.html

Comment: I first converted string to ASCII to HEX value in the code; At the RDLC level I converted back to string.